# Unreachable catch block for InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, exception, odata

I have code which is throwing an exception . In code below line container.setIsDefault(true) is throwing InvocationTargetException. I want to know actual cause of exception so I wrapped this code in try ..catch block.
But using try catch block is giving me compile time error
"Unreachable catch block for InvocationTargetException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

Any idea how can I figure out actual cause of exception.

```
try{
            EdmEntityContainer.Builder container= EdmEntityContainer.newBuilder();
            container.setName(dataBase);
            container.setIsDefault(true);
            container.setLazyLoadingEnabled(true);
            container.addEntitySets(entitySets);

            }catch (InvocationTargetException  e)
            {
                Throwable cause = e.getCause();
                System.out.format("Invocation of failed because of: %s%n", cause.getMessage());
            }
```

UPDATE:
I added RuntimeException and fake InvocationTargetException in code . But its not going into any of those catch blocks.Its directly going to below function where target is null

```
public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target) {
        super((Throwable)null);  // Disallow initCause
        this.target = target;
    }
```

Here is stacktrace,now exception is coming at line container.addEntitySets(entitySets);

```
InvocationTargetException.<init>(Throwable) line: 72    
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606  
JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(Method, Object, Object...) line: 60   
AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(Object, HttpContext) line: 205  
AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher).dispatch(Object, HttpContext) line: 75  
HttpMethodRule.accept(CharSequence, Object, UriRuleContext) line: 288   
ResourceClassRule.accept(CharSequence, Object, UriRuleContext) line: 108    
RightHandPathRule.accept(CharSequence, Object, UriRuleContext) line: 147    
RootResourceClassesRule.accept(CharSequence, Object, UriRuleContext) line: 84   
WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationContext, ContainerRequest) line: 1469   
WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationContext, ContainerRequest, ContainerResponse) line: 1400    
WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(ContainerRequest, ContainerResponse) line: 1349    
WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(ContainerRequest, ContainerResponseWriter) line: 1339  
ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent(WebComponent).service(URI, URI, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 416    
ServletContainer.service(URI, URI, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 537   
ServletContainer.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 708 
ServletContainer(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 848    
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 303  
ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
WsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 52    
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 220    
StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 122    
Authenticator(AuthenticatorBase).invoke(Request, Response) line: 501    
Authenticator.invoke(Request, Response) line: 197   
StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 170   
ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 98 
TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(Request, Response) line: 255  
TenantValidationValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 101   
RequestTracingValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 24  
RequestTracingValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 27  
StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 116 
CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 408  
Http11Processor(AbstractHttp11Processor<S>).process(SocketWrapper<S>) line: 1040    
Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler(AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler<S,P>).process(SocketWrapper<S>, SocketStatus) line: 607   
JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() line: 315 
ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1145  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 615   
TaskThread(Thread).run() line: 745 [local variables unavailable]
```

Comment: Are you sure it is thrown from those methods in the `try` block? That error message should be right in most cases. If so, add e.g. `if (false) throw new InvocationTargetException(null);` to trick the compiler into believing that the try block can throw it.

Comment: `public Builder setIsDefault(boolean isDefault) { this.isDefault = isDefault; return this; }` - What makes you think this is throwing an `InvocationTargetException`?

Comment: You can put the statement `throw new InvocationTargetException("fake exception");` at the bottom of the block, assuming that the code throws it every time and you don't have to go through the block multiple times to catch the error.  If you really want good help, post the entire class (w/ line numbers?) and the entire stack trace, instead of interpreting the error message halfway.  That gives us a chance to explain what's going on instead of just making guesses.

Comment: compilation error is gone but still unable to find root cause of exception.

Comment: Stop guessing and post the stack trace. And get rid of your own `InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: That is not a stack trace. That is *part* of the stack trace. The part that supports your incorrect assumptions, which in turn are causing this compile error. Post it all. There's a chunk missing from the top.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem here is that the exception is not actually a TargetInvocationException, but rather another exception wrapping it.

Update your catch block to be:

```
}catch (RuntimeException  e)
```

and see what happens.

Comment: @Alien01 then try to catch `Throwable`,  that catches anything that can be thrown in Java.

Comment: @Alien01 works with Throwable!  RuntimeException will not work, is a subclass of Exception.

Comment: I bet catching Throwable is not the most elegant or technically accurate way, but unless you are trying to do something very specific regarding this type of exception... it works! And it did the job for me beautifully, Thanks!